# Class to define a CSS Color to be used at model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating (some sort of) a html editor.
Many classes got a Color attribute

```
public class Widget
{
    public String Color {get;set;}
}
```

I want to change it to

```
public class Widget
{
    public ColorType Color {get;set;}
}
```

What I want is a ColorType class to define that attribute and that class ill only accept a valid Css color format like

```
#F0F0F0
#FFF
white
```

I guess it's easy to implement a regex validation and throw exception at the setter (there's a better way?)

The tricky part is I also want my models to use that regex to validate that properties inputs (any shortcut to just do it by declaring a decorator?)

```
public class Widget
{
    [Validate(IsColorType)]
    public ColorType Color {get;set;}
}
```